# Problems plotting Netcdf files in Panoply

Tags: netcdf

I can't create plot from .nc files using Panoply. The error message reads: "Axis contains NaN". Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

Change the NaNs to normal "missing values", then use Panoply. 
The netCDF Operator (NCO) command ncatted works with NaNs.
First set the missing value (i.e., the value of the _FillValue
attribute) for the variable(s) in question to the IEEE NaN value:

ncatted -a _FillValue,,o,f,NaN in.nc

Then change the missing value from the IEEE NaN value to a
normal IEEE number, like 1.0e36 (or to whatever the original
missing value was). Now use Panoply. More at

http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#NaN